# Issues in Highchart-treemap with drilldown data label color change

Tags: highcharts, treemap, drilldown

I am trying to change the datalabel color to white in highchart-treemap. It works totally fine when the drilldown is set to false(drilldown:false) in data array. Change is not getting reflected when it is set to true. I need white datalabels with drilldown. Please let me know if there is any work around for this. fiddle link is in the comment section.

Comment: here is the working fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/y7yem2v0/9/.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parameter called activeDataLabelStyle in Highcharts API:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle

You can use it for changing colour of your labels if you have drilldown.

Here you can find code that may help you:

```
drilldown: {
      activeDataLabelStyle: {
        color: 'white'
      },
}
```

And here you can find live example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/y7yem2v0/12/